# Java Looping issue in Hangman program(Cant find)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops

I have the majority of my program finished, but now that I have most of the code it is tough to find the errors. I have multiple errors at the moment, but the main error I really need help with is that my program will loop the same guess over & over if it is correct. It is in an infinite loop, & I cannot find where it is. This has also brought to my attention that my program will go into negative guesses as it is supposed to end when it gets to 0. Some other errors that would be nice to get help with is 1) it shows a correct guess as an incorrect guess 2) it can only replace one letter in the secret word if there are multiple it will give me an error & end the program. & 3) if I enter 9 to quit, it does not quit.

Thanks in advance for any help. I can add code if needed ( I am only posting the main body ATM.)

```
public static final int DICTIONARY = 15000;
    public static final int GUESSES = 8;
    public static final int SECRETLENGTH = 20;  



 public static void main(String[] args) {
            int usedSize = 0, randomWord, guesses = GUESSES;
            String word, secretWord, guess, incorrectGuess, correctWord, playAgain;
            char letter;
try
{   
    // Set up connection to the input file
    Scanner hangmanDictionary = new Scanner(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
    String [] dictionary = new String [DICTIONARY];
    while (usedSize < DICTIONARY && hangmanDictionary.hasNextLine()) {
        dictionary[usedSize] = hangmanDictionary.nextLine();
        usedSize++;
    }
kbd.nextLine();
            clearScreen();

    randomWord = pickRandom(DICTIONARY);
    word = dictionary[randomWord];

    secretWord = secret(word);

    //comment out when done testing
    System.out.println(word);


    System.out.println("Here is the word to guess: " + secretWord);
    System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess, or 9 to quit.");

    guess = kbd.next();

    do {
        while (!guess.equals("9") || !(guess.equals(word) && guesses > 0)) {
            letter = guess.charAt(0);
            incorrectGuess = "";
            incorrectGuess += letter;
            if (word.indexOf(letter) < 0) {
                guesses--;
                System.out.println("Incorrect guesses: " + incorrectGuess);
                System.out.println("Number of guesses left: " + guesses);
                System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess, or 9 to quit.");
                guess = kbd.next();
            }
            else {
                //FINSH THIS
                correctWord = correctWord(guess, word, secretWord, letter);
                System.out.println(correctWord);
                System.out.println("Incorrect guesses: " + incorrectGuess);
                System.out.println("Number of guesses left: " + guesses);
                System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess, or 9 to quit.");
                guesses--;
            }
        }
            if (guess.equals("9")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (guess.equals(word)) {
                System.out.println("You won!");
            }
            if (guesses == 0) {
                System.out.println("You are out of guesses.");
            }
            System.out.println("Play again? Y/N");
            playAgain = kbd.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    } while (playAgain.equals("Y"));

}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess:

Did you forget to put `guess = kbd.next();` if the user guessed a correct character?

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop is your main problem, i.e. think about what happens when you enter a valid letter (guess), in that case the first condition of the while loop OR condition is TRUE (assuming you don't have a 9 in your secret word), so the while loop is entered without entering the second part of the OR condition. After that you enter the else part of the IF statement (since it's a valid guess) but in the else part you're not asking for the next guess, so it returns to the start of the while loop with the same guess and hence infinite loop.

Similarly, if you enter 9 to exit `!guess.equals("9")` evaluates to FALSE, so the second part of the OR condition is entered, in the second part
`!(guess.equals(word) && guesses > 0)` evaluates to TRUE (unless the secret word contains a 9) so you enter the WHILE loop which is invalid. etc ...

Try to write small parts of the code using known parameters and then bring it all together, that way it'll be easier to construct and follow the logic.

Comment: ok, thanks for the input. I've changed the OR to AND & am getting a little bit of a different result now. After the first guess it now exits the whole loop & starts asking the user if they would like to play again.